# cURL login fills form but doesn't 'post'

Tags: php, curl, autologin

for an computer science project we have to build a website that presents our time schedules. So basically what we have to do, is login to [this](http://rooster.sgnphp.nl/) site and get the information out of the page you're directed to.
I've read a lot of posts and tried a lot with cURL, but nothing seems to work. 
I got the forms to be filled out, but it looks as if the 'submit' button isn't clicked. This is what I've got:

```
<?php
$url="http://rooster.sgnphp.nl/infoweb/index.php"; 
$post_data['user'] = '105353';
$post_data['paswoord'] = '105353';

foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) 
{
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}
$postdata = implode ('&', $post_items);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US;         rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, cookie.txt); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, cookie.txt); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 
echo $result;

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

The form which I tried to fill in looks like this:

```
<form action="/infoweb/index.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="cec30a2ed764e956ed01f137e2f0705a">
<table>
  <tbody><tr>
    <td>
      Gebruikersnaam:
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="mooi" style="color: #FF8080;" type="text" name="user" value="105353" onfocus="if (this.value =='username') this.value=''; this.style.color='#000000';" onkeydown="this.style.color='#000000';">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Wachtwoord:
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="mooi" style="margin-bottom: 2px; color: #FF8080;" type="password"     name="paswoord" value="105353" onfocus="if (this.value =='wachtwoord') this.value=''; this.style.color='#000000';" onkeydown="this.style.color='#000000';">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" name="login" value="loginform"> &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="submit" class="mooi" value="inloggen"><br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
</form>
```

So what happens is that the form is filled out, but I can't see the time schedule because (I think) I'm not officially logged in.
Can anybody please help me? I really need to get this to work so I can get on with the rest of my project, but I've been stuck on this for days.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how the login script works for that site depends on how you set up Curl.

At a glance I would guess that you would need to Curl the page first get a session started and save cookies then strip "csrf" input and then post your username and password.

From then on you would be able to Curl any link that requires you to be logged in.

If "you" built the site I'm sure you could make a a script that would do this for you?

Comment: @user2108808

Hi, thanks for replying. I don't know how to get a session started with cURL and I am not the creator of this site, so I cannot script my way in. Could you please help me or link me to a site that shows me how to do this first step and then strip the csrf?

Comment: http://allenprogram.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/php-auto-login-facebook-using-curl.html this a link that shows how to log into facebook. The basic idea is.

You first Curl GET the page into a variable then using substr you have to locate the form input csrf value "cec30a2ed764e956ed01f137e2f0705a" using that you Curl POST (with cookies) your login details and then the result is you have and active session that you can get to any restricted page.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the form has a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="login" value="loginform">
```

you need to send this value as well:

```
$post_data['login'] = 'loginform';
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I added 

    $post_data['login'] = 'loginform';

but when I did that everything goes blank. I just get a blank screen, not even the forms filled out. I also added the hidden crsf input, but that doesn't make any difference.